# JavaScript Session Cookie Being Deleted by Web App -- How to Debug?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have an issue with a session cookie being deleted somehow. The code that sets the cookie and reads it has been in place for years and works on most pages. I've tried some testing (cookie name I'm debugging is 'navElemName') and somehow the cookie appears to be deleted by the web app on specific pages? I've even tested (which is still in place) where I added another cookie within the same code that creates the 'navElemName' cookie (other cookie name is “navElemNameNotDeletedDuplicate” ) that has no code to delete it or interact with it in any way and that disappears also. I just need to figure out why? You can see this in action. I have 3 steps tracked by console.logs which start with “COOKIE TEST” and has the steps in the console log also which you should see when clicking any of the green “APPLY NOW” buttons. The Appy Now buttons have custom HTML-5 attributes that are read into the cookie, onclick, and then the web app reads the value of the cookie on the subsequent page. **If you go to this page below, you’ll see it works as designed**.

https://www.bankofthewest.com/campaigns/small-business/businesscards.html#testdtm

**But if you go to this page and click on a green “APPLY NOW” button:**

https://www.bankofthewest.com/campaigns/small-business/express-lending.html#testdtm

You’ll notice the cookie gets deleted before the next page can read it. I have no idea how to debug this issue? The code is injected via Adobe DTM. The cookie is set by an event-based rule which will be step 1 in the console logs and then is read on the subsequent page by a data element (steps 2 &3 in the console logs).

Any advice/direction or help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Going to `businesscards.html#testdtm` shows me: `COOKIE TEST -- Step 2 in Data ELement =====> NAV ELEMENT COOKIE VALUE RETRIEVED of : `. The value appears to be empty or `undefined` every time, even when I clear cookies completely before loading the page

Comment: I have an idea of how to debug it but I'm not sure I'm experiencing the same base behavior that you are

Comment: *** Sorry, I wasn't clear, you won't be actually testing and able to see the actual expected output until you click on the "APPLY NOW" button and go to the next page where the value is reported from those pages I listed.*** The output you are seeing is expected, as there was no value set when you load either of the pages I specified, only after clicking and going to next page My apologies!

Comment: **** Here is a screenshot of the working results page    http://squaredvisions.com/results.png ****

Comment: I couldn't figure this out so I actually used session storage instead of a cookie and that works fine.